# 2021 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

[Moderator election #1](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/election/1) on Veganism & Vegetarianism has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderators are:

[image: Nic]

[image: Zanna]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/election/1) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/4883971851681792).

Comment: Congrats to the winners, and thanks to all who participated!

Answer (score 7):

I'd like to express my gratitude to all the community members who voted in this election! Thank you for entrusting both Zanna and myself to uphold the values of this community. It's great to see that spirit of civic engagement -- just over 50% of people who visited the election page ended up voting.

I am looking forward to working with [Zanna](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/users/74/zanna) as we team up with the incumbent moderators [Erica](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/users/70/erica) and [Niitaku](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/users/77/niitaku).

And of course, I'd like to thank the community team at Stack Exchange for providing a space that makes all of this possible.

Comment: Congratulations! I wasn't expecting anyone to vote for me after I saw your nomination. With you on the team I have high hopes for the future of the site.

Comment: Congratulations Nic

Comment: Congratulations Nic!

Answer (score 7):

I'm so excited to have been elected to serve this community alongside Nic, Erica and Niitaku <3

Thank you so much to everyone who participated in the election, especially Nic and [Joe](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/users/20/joe) for putting in nominations.

Being helpful makes me happy so if I can do anything useful for y'all, just ask :)

Comment: Congrats! 80% is not something we see in a normal election.

Comment: Congratulations Zanna

Comment: Congrats Zanna!

Answer (score 5):

Congratulations to Zanna and Nic. I am not sad/upset in any way for not getting one of the moderator slots. I'm thrilled that the 2 much more qualified candidates were chosen.

My hope is that this community continues to grow, and is a great resource for everyone.

And my goal for myself is to try to become more involved, and learn more about the moderation process, so that someday when a slot is open, I could run again, and help contribute to the community.

Congrats again, and thank you for the community for getting involved.

Comment: :) thank you for making the election possible and for your kind words.

Comment: Thanks Joe, I'm glad you put your name forward! And I look forward to your ongoing contributions here; there's [so much](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) that community members can do to help maintain and improve the site.

Comment: Joe that is so wonderful to hear. I think everyone is looking forward to your contributions to the community. Thank you for throwing your hat in the ring. :)